# How to filter in django by two properties of the same related object in a many-to-one relationship?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, orm

My model structure looks like this:

```
class OneModel(model):
    not_important = IntegerField()


class RelatedModel():
    propertyA = IntegerField()
    propertyB = IntegerField()
    original = ForeignKey(OneModel, related_name='related')
```

I am looking for a native django solution (without raw sql), to recreating basically this query:

```
select * from OneModel om where not exists
(select id from RelatedModel rm where original_id = om.id and propertyA = 1 and propertyB = 2);
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
OneModel.objects.exclude(related__propertyA=1, related__propertyB=2)
```

Unfortunately this has the effect of selecting `OneModel` objects which have **neither** a related with `propertyA=1`, **nor** a related with `propertyB=2`, not ones that don't have a **single related** that matches **both** criteria.

Here's the generated sql from my django query:

```
SELECT lots_of_fields
FROM "OneModel"
WHERE NOT ("OneModel"."id" IN (SELECT U1."original_id" AS Col1
                               FROM "RelatedModel" U1
                               WHERE U1."PropertyA" = 1)
           AND
           "OneModel"."id" IN (SELECT U1."original_id" AS Col1
                               FROM "RelatedModel" U1
                               WHERE U1."PropertyB" = 2))
```

And just to be clear, my problem is not with using `"id" in` instead of exists, but with the logic of the query.

I tried playing around with Q-objects, but can't figure out any way to use to solve this. I also looked at F-objects, but they also don't seem to be relevant. Is there any way to express this in pure django, or do I have resolve to writing SQL?

As to why not just use SQL, I'll admit it's more just because of pride/wanting to learn something new than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually covered in the docs -- it's just a little hard to find.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) is the link: scroll down a bit to the green 
"note" section.

It essentially says that excluding based on foreign key is a bit unintuitive, and you can't do it in one query . Instead, this should work (I just ported their code to your names:

```
query = OneModel.objects.exclude(
    related__in=RelatedModel.objects.filter(
        propertyA=1,
        propertyB=2,
    ),
)
```

Django optimizes this so that, although it looks like two queries are happening, only one call to the DB is actually made. You can check the SQL call of this through `query.query` if you're curious.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for. I'll check and mark as accepted tomorrow. Thank you.